# Modifying the gridview elements in c# page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am developing a web application using asp.net with c# and the above line of codes will make me to display the gridview as below.
[image]

```
   DateTime startDate;
    DateTime endDate;

    if (DateTime.TryParse(txtstart.Text, out startDate) && DateTime.TryParse(txtend.Text, out endDate))
    {
        //string n1 = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text;

        if (DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text == "Membership")
        {
            SqlConnection con = new
      SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ProjectConnectionString"].ToString());
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("select p.Name,m.FID,m.MembNo,m.MembType,m.Validity,m.Remarks,m.Organisation,m.UpdateDate from Membership_det m INNER JOIN Personal_det p  ON m.FID= p.FID where m.updateDate  between @Start and @End ", con);
            adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Start", SqlDbType.Date).Value = startDate;
            adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@End", SqlDbType.Date).Value = endDate;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            con.Close();
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        log.Debug("Info: Admin viewed the membership details");
    }
```

Now in the `gridview` I have `UpdateDate` column which is displaying the datetime because in the database I have stored it as `Datetime`,Now instead of `Datetime` I need to display only `Date` i.e Instead of this `11/23/2013 12:00:00 AM` I need this `11/23/2013`.
Any suggestions are appreciated.As far as i know the `data source binding` can be done in aspx page but i just needed code on `c#`.

In aspx

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"></asp:GridView>
```

Comment: You should post your asp-code too. Probably you need to add a format string in the binding of the UpdateDate column in the GridView1-control

Answer (score 1):

You can use Tostring("MM/dd/yyyy") on GridView RowDataBound event by accessing the Updated Date columns of the gridview.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create grid columns manually and set `DataFormatString` of `UpdateDate` column to a desired value.
2. You can create a class for `GridView`s `ColumnsGenerator` property. And in that class when `UpdateDate` column is generated you can set `DataFormatString`.

Comment: I just need the code in c#,yes you are right we can do that in aspx page.

Comment: try `((BoundField)GridView1.Columns[7]).DataFormatString = "d";`

Answer (score 0):

Please convert the DateTime into the Short date format,using ToShortDateString() Method.

Better use the SQLDataReader object insted of SQLDataAdopter object;

```
   SqlDataReader dr=cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

to fill datagridview read row by row using dr.getstring('Column-No') and add it to the Datatable / Gridview Row and This is one way to do it;

Otherwise Use the below Alternative Method:

---

using DataAdopter itself:

1. Take another table (DataTable) xxx
2. From DataTable 1 (Already filled) Transfer it to Datatable2(xxx)
3. In Between While Transfering Just change the Dateformat by DateTime.ToShortDateString() method.
4. Finally Change DataGridview.datasource=DataTable2(xxx);

Answer (score 0):

On `RowDataBound` 11/23/2013 12:00:00 AM

```
 void GridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  //change the value to `string x = dt.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");`
     if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {

     // string time = ((Label)e.Row.FindControl("UpdateDate")).Text;
      string time =Convert.ToString(e.Row.Cells[7].Text);
      e.Row.Cells[7].Text =time.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");`

    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

If your cell number changes according to your selected value then a better way would be format it in aspx check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/) or you can format it in your `query`.

Comment: You can see the drop down list,it has different items so the column might not be `7` every time it might change.So what might be other possibility?